# React Native RedBox error will not be dismissed in IOS simulator

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I am using create-reactive-native-app and expo (latest versions). When my app hot-reloads with a syntax error, the iOS simulator will show a RedBox error, which is fine. However, it gets stuck there even if the syntax error is fixed.

[image]

Reloading via the hotkey works, as console indicates:

```
12:29:28 PM: Finished building JavaScript bundle in 30ms
12:29:28 PM: Running app on Hackintosh in development mode
```

each time I press it. However, the RedBox error remains and the app is not shown. Dismissing it with ESC has no effect.

The only way to get the app back is to restart the IOS simulator, which is of course, a huge hassle when developing.

Any solutions to this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Clicking (touching) Dismiss (ESC) worked, even though actual ESC keypress did not.